# How to show Only rows 95-100 of column in expressions editor in print compositor?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-expression

I have two columns: One for the name of regions (column a) and another with index values for the regions (column b).

Now I want to show a List for the regions only row 95 to 100 in the print compositor e.g. in the map legend of qgis, that shows the names of those five regions with their (descending) index values.

How do I define this in the expressions editor for the map legend?